# When should one publish code publicly on GitHub: during or after journal review?

Tags: publications, journals, code

Similar to the [following question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17740/open-source-the-project-code-before-or-after-publication), I have developed a code to produce results in a manuscript that I've written which I wish to now share with the community. But this manuscript, which is currently on arXiv, is still under journal review (which has taken several months and still sits with the referees). Therefore, I was wondering if I should put the code publicly on Github while the manuscript remains under review or only after the manuscript has been fully accepted/published by a journal? Does the right answer depend on the journal? Is it better to wait for any reason(s)? Any and all insights are welcome.

Comment: How did you make code available to the reviewers? Is this a bespoke analysis of something or is the code the product?

Comment: @Libor The journal/reviewers have not requested the code directly (at least thus far). The manuscript is essentially applying and benchmarking the code which is a data analysis technique that can be easily adapted to different data sets.

Comment: @Mathews24 Speaking as a reviewer: The fact that the reviewer agreed to go ahead without _insisting_ on the code first does not mean that they were not annoyed, and does not mean that you didn't make their job harder by withholding the code. The importance of the code depends on the specific paper and can range from irrelevant to critical. However, purposefully withholding it only until after the review is counterproductive and might be wasting the reviewer's time.

Comment: Follow-up question: do you need to anonymize a published code base for a double-blind review?

Comment: @moooeeeep Nope, there is no requirement to anonymize a published code base for a double-blind review

Comment: @Szabolcs If there was a place to provide code, I would've gladly obliged during the initial submission process. This is a physics journal and I suspect it's likely uncommon for code to be requested/submitted in general.

Comment: @Mathews24 My field is also physics. The customary way to provide code is to host it at a location of your choice (such as GitHub) then insert a link into the manuscript, or provide the link with the "code availability statement" (if the journal requests one).  The publisher will not host the code for you.

Comment: @Szabolcs Correct, I have included a link to the Github repository in the manuscript. The repository is just set to private at the moment and I was wondering if making it public is recommended at this point or if one should wait after journal review (i.e. the purpose of the question).

Comment: On a related note, arXiv has [the `anc` directory](https://arxiv.org/help/ancillary_files), which I find is a nice place to archive code that's very closely related to a particular paper, even when I host it on github.  (Phys Rev D, for example, will just point to such a directory, rather than hosting it in their own supplemental materials.)  [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org) also has nice automation for archiving releases of your code and [making them citable](https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Particular to your situation, I think the exact answer is highly dependent on some missing information:

- How do you plan to license the code once released?
- Do you have some sort of agreement with the journal that the code is part of the manuscript that they will own the copyright to?

In General: When should one release the code relative to publication? Before! (Allow me to explain)

My knee-jerk response was "why isn't the code already on GitHub (or another hosting site)"?
By publicly posting the code, publicly affiliating yourselves to it, and having a time-stamped "paper" trail of commits. I would expect this provides a good hedge against being "scooped", similar to, but more robust than, the old signed-and-dated lab books for maintaining development records in the case of IP/patent disputes.
I work, directly or indirectly (and often in a very minor way) on computational chemistry code, but we write the code and store it in a GitHub repo where it's public facing and has open source licenses. The code either gets cited in papers that use it (not necessarily well - see [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/164177/are-software-citations-indexed/164179)) and/or there's an article written up detailing the software that provide details specific to it (and maybe even later publications of new major versions with added features, e.g. [RMG](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2016.02.013) and [RMG 3](https://doi.org/10.26434/chemrxiv.13489656.v1) with actively-developed source [here](https://github.com/ReactionMechanismGenerator/RMG-Py))

Comment: I have published few github repos related to papers and I've done both, before and after. I fully agree with this answer: publish your code in github early, particularly more if there is already a preprint or submitted paper (you can always reference an article submited for publication in a repo)

Comment: I plan to use an MIT License. There is no such formal copyright agreement with the journal regarding the code that I am aware of.

Comment: MIT open-source license / the journal doesn't have rights to it = I would post it now

Comment: Furthermore, if the code is not part of the journal submission, if you publish the code prior to submission, then the reviewers have more detailled information to review. That is however strongly field-dependent.

Answer (score 14):

You should post it *before* the paper is sent for review. Your paper is already on arXiv, and you do plan to make the code public after publication, so I see little reason to be secretive with it just for the duration of the review.

With certain types of papers, the review can be much more productive (and also easier for the reviewer) if the reviewer has access to the code. In *some* cases, having access to the code is critical for the review.

Answer (score 13):

The concerns to weigh are:

- Scooping. Your manuscript is already out on Arxiv, so there is no risk that someone will publish your same result earlier than you. By publishing code, you make it easier for other researchers to publish follow-up works. Is this something you want? Generally yes: more science, more reproducibility, more common world knowledge, and, more selfishly, more reputation in the community and more citations for you! But some prefer to keep their cards close to their chest, especially if they are already working on a natural follow-up.
- Anonymity. Is this a double-blind submission where you wish to hide your identity? I suppose not, in your case, since there is a preprint already out on Arxiv, so you are already non-anonymous.
- Replication. The referees may want to try your code and replicate your results. In some journals/areas, the code is considered a part of your paper, so if that is egregiously badly written that would reflect badly on your manuscript.
- License. Some journals forbid you to publish post-prints, because they already incorporate their 'work' (that referees and editors did for free for them). In theory, this could extend to code, so it is better to get it out early, when they can make no claim. I am not sure if it is even legal (and I am not sure if publishers ever sued anyone to enforce that clause or sent out DMCA requests to Github), but if you want the publishers to keep their greedy hands off your code it's better to publish it before submission (and the same applies to preprints).

[The standards on all these points vary](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4471/958) in different fields, and individual researchers have different opinions, so it is difficult to give a unique catch-all answer. At least in my field, though, sharing code is considered a [good thing](https://sinews.siam.org/Details-Page/top-ten-reasons-to-not-share-your-code-and-why-you-should-anyway) and I encourage you to do it.

Answer (score 10):

I frequently end up reviewing papers where code is a portion of the results, and in that case if the code isn't provided I'll ask for it while reviewing the other parts of the paper that I *can* review. If the paper is entirely about a computational method and the code isn't included I turn it right back around to the editor with "Unreviewable without the code". I think this is necessary, because I would say that 90% of my review for these types of papers can be summarized as "Write a better methods section and write tests for your code".

I'm going to add one thing to the other answers (which are all quite good). It's very helpful to me to have a versioned release on GitHub (or PyPi or CRAN or conda or Zenodo, or really whatever release channel you want) that's the exact version that you used for your analysis. I do occasionally have the desire to see how a specific thing was implemented, and if it's buried in 700 commits because you're still working on your software (which is totally fine), it's really hard to figure out where your results came from.

Comment: _> It's very helpful to me to have a versioned release..._ I'd call that an understatement: it should be **mandatory good practice** to be referring to a specific defined version; if the peer reviewers find it really hard to recreate the actual code used then what chance do the rest of us have?

Comment: Why would a paper about a computational methods be unreviewable without code? I rarely see code provided in JCP.